# C# ConfigurationErrorsException in custom configuration

Tags: c#, xml, configuration

I made the following custom configuration with the help of msdn example. It returns a System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException which says it cannot load my handler class from assembly System.Configuration.

What am i doing wrong?

**Configuaration:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="FTPLastModifiedGroup">
      <section
        name="FTPLastModified"
        type="DailyChecQ.CheckModules.FTPLastModified.Settings.FTPLastModifiedHandler"
        allowLocation="true"
        allowDefinition="Everywhere"
      />
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>
  <FTPLastModifiedGroup>
    <FTPLastModified enabled="true">
    </FTPLastModified>
  </FTPLastModifiedGroup>
</configuration>
```

**Handler**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Configuration;

namespace DailyChecQ.CheckModules.FTPLastModified.Settings {
    class FTPLastModifiedHandler : ConfigurationSection {

        [ConfigurationProperty("enabled", DefaultValue = "true", IsRequired = false)]
        public Boolean Enabled {
            get {
                return (Boolean)this["enabled"];
            }
            set {
                this["enabled"] = value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Loading the configuration which causes the error.

```
FTPLastModifiedHandler config = (FTPLastModifiedHandler) ConfigurationManager.GetSection("FTPLastModifiedGroup/FTPLastModified");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are missing here is the Assembly name of the type which you configured for handling the configuration section. If the Assemblyname is not provided, .NET will look for that class in `System.Configuration` assembly which causes this issue.

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="FTPLastModifiedGroup">
      <section name="FTPLastModified"
         type="DailyChecQ.CheckModules.FTPLastModified.Settings.FTPLastModifiedHandler, 
              {{YourAssemblyName}}"
        allowLocation="true"
        allowDefinition="Everywhere"
      />
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>
  <FTPLastModifiedGroup>
    <FTPLastModified enabled="true">
    </FTPLastModified>
  </FTPLastModifiedGroup>
</configuration>
```

**YourAssemblyName** is the name of the Assembly where class `FTPLastModifiedHandler` is defined. Once you make this change the issue will be resolved.